# Supporting of GUID Type in grpc service Net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

Net Core 3.0 is come out. Now there is a possibility to create and host a grpc service on ASP.NET Core.

We start a creation of grpc service with description of a contract of that service in [proto files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#c-tooling-support-for-proto-files).

But I don't know how to describe a message with GUID field type.
It is a not built-in type, it is just a struct. But that type is widely used everywhere. May be say, it is used as a built-in type in the webservices.

The GUID struct is used in other kinds of .NET services like WCF, ASP.NET(Core) Web API without any additional actions.

As for the proto3 language, it has not a Well-Known GUID type. All Well-Known types are [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/namespace/google/protobuf/well-known-types).

Therefore I have a question, how to describe GUID type in the proto file in ASP NET Core 3.0? Are should we create an additional message? Or may be is there a proto file with description of GUID type which can be just imported?

I didn't find any useful information. I also didn't find a proto file contained UUID message [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/src/google/protobuf).

Comment: You can pass it as bytes or string type.
Try looking [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36363082/12030195).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I represent a UUID in a protobuf message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344826/how-do-i-represent-a-uuid-in-a-protobuf-message)

Comment: I don't quite agree that this is a duplicate. My question is specifically about supporting the use of UUIDs in ASP NET Core grpc services. As I understand far, every developer of Net Core 3.0 will reinvent your bike

Comment: Ultimately, gRPC doesn't have an opinion on the serialize step - that is left to the marshaller, and people *usually* use protobuf as the marshaller for gRPC, which means : this is a protobuf question, hence the duplicate