# Updating from Infinispan 7 to 10, how to deal with UUID as key of UUID as field in a class?

Tags: java, marshalling, infinispan

I am trying to update a big project that was using Infinispan 7 to the v10.1.3.

I would like to use the new protostream marshaller, but I don't understand how to be able to use UUID as cache key, or even (easier ?) as a field in a class that I want to insert in a cache.

My cache was accessed like that : `Map<UUID, Foo> testUUIDAsKey = manager.getCache("t1");`

Here when trying to put a value into the cache, infinispan tells me that he don't know how to marshal an uuid.

Ok, so after reading the documentation, I tryied to switch to a easier test case : `Map<String, Bar> testUUIDAsField = manager.getCache("t2");`

Here, the Bar class have a field of type UUID, and I tried to use the protostream annotation processor that will generated and build a proto file automatically when the right annotation are used.

But this time, the annotation processor tells me that UUID class must be instantiable using an accessible no-argument constructor.

I know that protobuf can't manage UUID, I can store the value as string or by storing the 2 long values part of an uuid.

How can I register a UUID marshaller that would use String as it representation in the end ?

And how can I tell the annotation processor that it must use this marshaller ?

Then, how can I use UUID as a key ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Infinispan registers a Protostream marshaller for the UUID, but unfortunately it is only in the server. I have created [ISPN-11426](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-11426) to make it so that UUIDs will be marshallable out of the box in embedded mode in future releases (10.1.4.Final and 11.x).

In the mean time, you can get UUIDs to work as the key by creating a SerializationContextInitializer and defining a `UUIDMarshaller`class:

```java
       public static class Initializer implements SerializationContextInitializer {

          @Override
          public String getProtoFileName() {
             return "org.example.package.proto";
          }

          @Override
          public String getProtoFile() throws UncheckedIOException {
             return "package org.example.package;\n" +
                   "message UUID {\n" +
                   "    optional string value = 1;\n" +
                   "}\n";
          }

          @Override
          public void registerSchema(SerializationContext serCtx) {
             serCtx.registerProtoFiles(org.infinispan.protostream.FileDescriptorSource.fromString(getProtoFileName(), getProtoFile()));
          }

          @Override
          public void registerMarshallers(SerializationContext serCtx) {
             serCtx.registerMarshaller(new UUIDMarshaller("org.example.package.UUID"));
          }
       }
```

```java
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import org.infinispan.protostream.MessageMarshaller;

    public class UUIDMarshaller implements MessageMarshaller<UUID> {

       private final String typeName;

       /**
        * @param typeName so that marshaller can be used in multiple contexts
        */
       public UUIDMarshaller(String typeName) {
          this.typeName = typeName;
       }

       @Override
       public UUID readFrom(ProtoStreamReader reader) throws IOException {
          return UUID.fromString(reader.readString("value"));
       }

       @Override
       public void writeTo(ProtoStreamWriter writer, UUID uuid) throws IOException {
          writer.writeString("value", uuid.toString());
       }

       @Override
       public Class<? extends UUID> getJavaClass() {
          return UUID.class;
       }

       @Override
       public String getTypeName() {
          return typeName;
       }
    }
```

You will need to update the `org.example.package` to something relevant to your project.

The Initializer class can then be provided programmatically via:

`new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().serialization().addContextInitializer(new Initializer());`

Or via xml:

```xml
      <serialization>
         <context-initializer class="org.example.package.Initializer" />
      </serialization>
```

Comment: Note that `UUIDMarshaller` is an internal class, so it might move or disappear.

Comment: Thanks @DanBerindei this is only temporary waiting for the ISPN-11426 to be solved.

Comment: Thank you @RyanEmerson but I have read that serializing UUID using 2 long might not be a good idea, any experience with the new infinispan ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344826/how-do-i-represent-a-uuid-in-a-protobuf-message via https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2224

Comment: For Infinispan internal use, representing the UUID as two longs should not be an issue as the protobuf representation is always consumed via Java. However, I have updated the example to show how you can represent the UUID as a String to avoid these concerns. As @DanBerindei states, `UUIDMarshaller` is an internal class that might be removed, so I would recommend creating your own local version of the class.

Comment: `org.infinispan.protostream.MessageMarshaller` is @Deprecated since protostream 4.3.1.  Is there a way that does not use a class that is going to be removed?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the minute. Long term the plan is to provide support for generating [Marshallers and schemas for external classes](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/IPROTO-137), however the `MessageMarshaller` interface will not be removed until an alternative is available.